# How to use the date format that has been setup as default in Settings?

Tags: locale, date-format, android

As you probably know, you can setup date format in the Settings of an Android device.

In code how do we make sure that we use that format for date display?

Comment: @Y.S. I don't know how to help you there. Maybe try to open an official bug report with a sample app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `android.text.format.DateFormat`, notably [`getDateFormatOrder()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormatOrder%28android.content.Context%29) to get the user's preferred date format.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve both the date format as well as the time format like this:

```
DateFormat timeFormat;
DateFormat dateFormat;

dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
```